# Redirect many old asp pages in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, seo

I have converted a site from .asp to .php pages

now I need to redirect many old .asp pages to the home page

the structure of the .asp URLs is:

```
/dettagli.asp?ID=123456789
```

I would like any /dettagli.asp page to be redirected to the home page, regardless of the parameter which is passed (these ages no longer exist...)
I have tried some regex so far but no luck....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule as your very first rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^dettagli\.asp$ /? [L,R=302]
```

Comment: First  verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit your page in browser?

Comment: yes it is enabled, I am using joomla and already made some redirect of some static asp pages to new urls and they are working...

Comment: What is full URL that gave 404? Also make sure to keep this rule as very first rule.

Comment: see it:

http://www.sagreinitalia.it/dettagli.asp?ID_S={CF9DE1DA-C652-4E00-A710-9FEDA6023C30}

Answer (score 0):

Solved. 
I simply was using rules AFTER Joomla Rules that were applied BEFORE mine...